# Left circular moving

Tags: c

The code contains Right Circular moving which is for example the number **12345** will be **51234**.

the question is how i can make **left circular moving** which is for example **12345** will be **23451**, my number is bettween 3 digits to 10 not only 5 digits. Please Help?

Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int mPow(long n, long b);
long Counts(long);
int main() {
long q;
printf("Please Enter a number \n");
scanf("%ld",&q);
printf("Right Rotate:%ld \n",(q%10)*(mPow(10,Counts(q)-1))+q/10);

return 0;
}
long Counts(long q) {
int count=0;
      while(q!=0) {
               q/=10;
               count++;
}
return count;
}
long mPow(long n,long b) { //n=>Base, b=>power
long ret=1;
while(b!=0) {
        ret = ret*n;
        b--;
 }
 }
```

Comment: Marcel, welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is not clear as to what is it that you need. Please be specific and show what you have tried till now. Please check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What do you mean without arrays ?

Comment: The solution will involve three things: taking the right-most digit, shifting everything to the right, and prepending the digit to your number. Which have you tried and which are you having trouble with?

Comment: What is the question? Please code `RightRotateDigit(int num)` for me?

Comment: Are you allowed to handle your input as a string rather than an integer? That would make this exercise much simpler.

Comment: @SumitTrehan i cant use arrays in my homework but here idk if it's useful to use but, never mind.

Comment: @Govind Parmar i still didnt reached strings but, it would be great if you can show me how it is simpler. Thank you

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin i want to know what's the difference to do with left rotation and right rotation i already done right rotation. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// steps:
// number example : 12345
// get the first digit : 5
// get the rest number : 1234
// get the number of digit in rest number : 4
// shifted number : rest number + firstDigit x 10^(num of digit)
//                : 1234        + 5          x 10^4
//                : 1234        + 50000 =   51234
int rotateRight(int num) {
    int firstDigit = num % 10;
    int restNumber = num / 10;
    int numberOfDigit = 0;
    int temp = restNumber;
    while (temp != 0) {
        temp /= 10;
        numberOfDigit++;
    }
    return restNumber + firstDigit * pow(10, numberOfDigit);
}

int main() {
    int num = 12345;
    cout << rotateRight(num) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't use `using namespace std` in answers. It's a VERY bad habit. Also, the question is about C and not C++, so you might as well delete this answer. (Yes, I know the question had the C++ tag before. It's a common mistake.)

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <math.h>

int getdig(int n){          //to get the no of digits in a number
  int count=0;
  while(n%10>0){
    count ++;
    n=n/10;
  }
  return count;
}

int RightRotateDigit(int num) {           //exmpl 12345
  int rightmost=num%10;                    //get the last digit 5
  num=num-rightmost;                       // num is now 12340
  num=num/10;                               //num is now 1234
  int dig=getdig(num)                     //get the no of digits in 1234 i.e 4
  int add=rightmost*pow(10,dig) ;         //5*10000=50000
  num=num+add;                             //num is now 51234
  return num;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Hi this logic might help you with you problem

```
int r=0,num = 12345;
r = num % 10;
num = num / 10;
num = r * 10000 + num;
/* print num and your answer will be 51234 */
```

Comment: why do you hardcode the value 10000?..the number will not always be 5 digit long

Comment: i am just giving the answer of particular query. This logic is called palandrom. You can find full code online for your search for palandrom a number.